# I have to edit one element in a dataframe. How to to it?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe -

```
      first_name last_name  Location Qualification
1        Saif     Mehdi Hyderabad        M.Tech
2       Rishi     Gupta      Pune        B.Tech
3       Aditi    Pandey   unknown        unkown
4      Poorwa    Kunwar     Japan        B.Tech
5      Rajesh Choudhary    Jaipur        B.Tech
6        Hari     Desai    Mumbai        M.Tech
7       Sayan       Das   Kolkata        B.Tech
8   Deepjyoti     Borah   Kolkata        B.Tech
9    Bharathi Ganesan R    Trichy        M.Tech
10   Jayarama   Krishna     Vizag        M.Tech
11      Akhil  Gopinath  Banglore           M.S
```

Now I want to edit the 4th row's Qualification column

How to do it?

I am new to R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `Qualification` column via `df$Qualification`, where `df` is your data frame. Then, you can access the 4th element of that via `df$Qualification[4]`. To replace the existing value with a new value, `new_value`, you can write: `df$Qualification[4] <- new_value`.

Comment: If that solves your issue, feel free to accept the response. Thanks!

Comment: @SaifMehdi Another possibility is `df[4,4] <- new_value` where `[4,4]` means `[row,column]`

Comment: @infinitefactors I'm trying to do but it's asking me to wait for 7 minutes